# Why do the title and x label not print in the graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code generates a plot but the title and the x label do not appear.

```
normalDistribution = np.random.normal(loc = 0.0, scale = 1.0, size = totalPoints)
rows = 4
columns = 5
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(24, 24))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.4) # to adjust the spacing between subplots
plt.subplot(rows, columns,1)
plt.title = "Normal Dist"
plt.xlabel = "Sequence #"
plt.scatter(range(0, len(normalDistribution)), normalDistribution, c='green')
```

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Add `plt.tight_layout()` at the end of your code

http://omz-software.com/pythonista/matplotlib/users/tight_layout_guide.html

```
normalDistribution = np.random.normal(loc = 0.0, scale = 1.0, size = totalPoints)
rows = 4
columns = 5
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(24, 24))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.4) # to adjust the spacing between subplots
plt.subplot(rows, columns,1)
plt.title = "Normal Dist"
plt.xlabel = "Sequence #"
plt.scatter(range(0, len(normalDistribution)), normalDistribution, c='green')

plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a figure, example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('insert a title', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=16)
fig.savefig('test.jpg')
```

I don't know that is possible, print the figure.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `plt.title()` and `plt.xlabel()` methods** 
`plt.title =` and `plt.xlabel =` will overwrite the functions your're looking to use.

```py
normalDistribution = np.random.normal(loc = 0.0, scale = 1.0, size = 1000)
rows = 4
columns = 5
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(24, 24))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.4) # to adjust the spacing between subplots
plt.subplot(rows, columns,1)

plt.title("Normal Dist")
plt.xlabel("Sequence #")

plt.scatter(range(0, len(normalDistribution)), normalDistribution, c='green')
```

[image]

- [plt.title() doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html)
- [plt.xlabel() doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html)